# Select two table and order by date

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to list out the latest update from two table `doc_to_do` and `doc_bug_tracker` below is my table structure

**doc_to_do**
[image]

**doc_bug_tracker**
[image]

and this is my current query :

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT p.*, 
        dtd.projects_id as dtd_projects_id, dtd.content as dtd_content, dtd.date_modified as dtd_date_modified,
        dbt.projects_id as dbt_projects_id, dbt.content as dbt_content, dbt.date_modified as dbt_date_modified 
        FROM `projects` p LEFT JOIN `doc_to_do` dtd ON p.id=dtd.projects_id 
        LEFT JOIN `doc_bug_tracker` dbt ON p.id=dbt.projects_id 
        where p.id="'.$project_id.'"');
```

so now how to order by `date_modified` either from table `doc_to_do` or `doc_bug_tracker` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get *only* the latest date (as opposed to all dates, ordered descending) try this:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  MAX(GREATEST(dtd.date_modified, dbt.date_modified)) AS MaxDate
FROM projects p
LEFT JOIN doc_to_do dtd ON p.id = dtd.projects_id
LEFT JOIN doc_bug_tracker dbt ON p.id = dbt.projects_id
WHERE p.id = <project_id>
GROUP BY p.id
```

If you need additional columns in your `SELECT`, be sure to include them in your `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
'SELECT x.* FROM 
(
    SELECT p.*, 
        dtd.projects_id as dtd_projects_id, dtd.content as dtd_content, dtd.date_modified as dtd_date_modified,
        dbt.projects_id as dbt_projects_id, dbt.content as dbt_content, dbt.date_modified as dbt_date_modified 
        FROM `projects` p LEFT JOIN `doc_to_do` dtd ON p.id=dtd.projects_id 
        LEFT JOIN `doc_bug_tracker` dbt ON p.id=dbt.projects_id 
        where p.id="'.$project_id.'"
) x
ORDER BY x.date_modified ASC'
```